# Handle push notification on background

Tags: windows-phone-8, push-notification, mpns

I am developing an application in windows phone which having push notification facility. I am able to receive push message at device.

If Application is not running , I am getting message at home screen on the click of that msg it starts that application. I want to perform some task on the basis of that Push Notification Message. But i am not able to handle that event.

Please help me to handle that EVENT if application is running or application is in background or application is not running .

Thanking You,

Answer (score 0):

Which type of notification are you sending? Based on your question I assume you are referring to toast notifications.

When do you want to perform the task - before or after the user clicks on the message? If the application is not running, you can only do it after clicking the message.

Comment: yes I am referring toast notification. I handle perfectly when my application is running.but when my application is in backgroung at that time how can I handle?